# R (Mac) freezes when opening script

Tags: r, macos

R.app - or rather the GUI - on Mac freezes frequently when opening a (script) file. It doesn't matter whether it is during starting (via the Dock-Icon) or in R, and whether the script is on the main HD or on a network drive.

This has been going on for a few years with different versions of R.app and Mac OS X, but it seems to be getting progressively worse - hence I assume that it must be a configuration problem.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: It probably autosaved a huge crashfile or binary image of a previous session. Double-check the configuration make sure it isn't l. Also, delete any image or session files. And you can invoke with `R --no-save --no-restore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably autosaved a huge crashfile or binary image of a previous session (`.RData`); these can be gigabytes. Double-check the configuration (if you're using RStudio or other IDE) to make sure it isn't. Also, delete any image or session files.

1. to be sure you're not, invoke from command-line with `R --no-save --no-restore`

- to see all the switches, `R --help` or read the [R MacOS help](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html) on console switches.

2. search for and delete image/session files (`./.RData` and similar dot-files. Delete them (or at least, hide/rename them if they might actually have come from a useful session.)
3. fail that, start R in a clean directory.
4. fail that uninstall-reinstall R itself (the nuclear option). But at least, try to figure out why it's creating/hanging/reloading large files, because R does this sometimes and that's usually the cause.

Comment: Look at `./.RData` and similar dot-files. Hide/delete them; they can be gigabytes. Also, [R MacOS help](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html). Faili that, start R in a clean directory. Fail that uninstall-reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks - it must be a local problem. Some of the files are on a server, and I can open them from a different machine without problems.

Comment: R sometimes crashes and leaves dirty messes. Obviously first check your invocation and configuration. But also it's common to have cleanup scripts (e.g. run via cron-job or on-demand) to find and delete such cruft.